# Error undefined columns selected

Tags: r

Estoy intentando ejecutar la función egltable a partir de un fichero importado:

```
  variables_descriptivos <- read.csv("Variables_names.csv", 
                 encoding = "ISO-8859-1",sep= ";",
                 check.names = F,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header = T)
```

Este input empieza así:

```
    Variables_names
    1 Edad
    2 Sexo (M/F)
    3 Peso
    4 Talla
    5 IMC
    6 Raza(caucásica/negra/latinoamericana/asiática/india)
    7 Tabaquismo (SI/NO/EXFUMADOR)
    8 Comorbilidades (SI/NO)
    9 Cardiopatía isquémica (SI/NO)
    10 Valvulopatía (SI/NO)
```

Al ejecutar la función egltable me aparece el siguiente error:

```
   table_parametric<-egltable(c(variables_descriptivos[1:54,]),         
                       data = BD_total, strict=TRUE);table_parametric

   Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , vars, drop = FALSE) :
```

undefined columns selected

He seleccionado las filas que quiero ¿Dónde tengo el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la ayuda de `egltable` el primer argumento es `vars`, que debe ser un índice (numérico o de caracteres) de variables que van a estar disponibles en `data`. En tu código le estás pasando una lista (el `c()` coerciona el data.frame a lista) de datos, no un vector de nombres o posiciones.

Esta versión debería funcionar:

```
table_parametric <- egltable(1:54,   #Aquí van los números de índice
                           data = BD_total,   #Aquí el data.frame con los datos
                           strict=TRUE)
table_parametric
```

PD: que dependencias pesadas tiene `JWileymisc`.

Comment: En efecto, ese era el fallo. Tras aplicar tu correción ha funcionado correctamente, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Si, tarda mucho en cargar el paquete JWileymisc, aunque empecé a optimizar el script con esta función no descarto pasarme en un futuro cercano a otra que me preste el mismo servicio. Gracias @mpaladino